# parallelize() method while using SparkSession in Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark

I see that `SparkSession` doesn't have `.parallelize()` method, Do we need to use `SparkContext` again to create a RDD?. If so, is creating both `SparkSession` & `SparkContext` in a single program advisable?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Once you build your SparkSession, you can fetch the underlying SparkContext created with it as followed :

Let's consider that SparkSession is already defined :

```
val spark : SparkSession = ???
```

You can get SparkContext now :

```
val sc = spark.sparkContext
```

Comment: It's the same for pyspark:

`# Create RDD
rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize()`

Answer (score 1):

There is method of spark Context in the SparkSession Class

```
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3,4))
data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:23
```